# nested NVL query issue

Tags: sql, error-handling, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to query an amazon redshift database with the following query:

```
NVL(SUM(CASE WHEN (original_price>0) THEN (original_price - sale_price1) 
ELSE (NVL(savings_low,0)) END),0)
```

However, this gives a

> Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "NVL"

error.

This was adapted from the original mySQL query, which looked like this (and works in mysql):

```
IFNULL(SUM(IF(original_price>0, original_price - sale_price1, 
IFNULL(savings_low,0))),0)
```

Can anybody see what's wrong with this, and suggest a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That portion of your select statement is perfectly valid. You can validate it with the following query, which tests all eight combinations of null and non-null values:

```
with mock_data as
(
SELECT NULL::integer as original_price, null::integer as sale_price1, null::float as savings_low UNION ALL
SELECT 100,  50,   0.10   UNION ALL
SELECT 100,  50,   NULL   UNION ALL
SELECT 100,  NULL, 0.10   UNION ALL
SELECT 100,  NULL, NULL   UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 50,   0.10   UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 50,   NULL   UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, 0.10
)


SELECT NVL(
  SUM(
  CASE WHEN (original_price > 0)
  THEN (original_price - sale_price1) 
  ELSE (NVL (savings_low,0))
  END)
,0)
FROM mock_data
```

The syntax error is elsewhere in your query: my suspicion is that the previous thing in your SELECT statement is missing the trailing comma.